# javascript: creating a local scope of a global variable undefines it before it is set

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, local, undefined

I do not understand this behavior:

```
var a = 1;
console.log('a is undefined1:', a == undefined);
var a;

//iterate selected jQuery elements:
jQuery.each(this, function(index, htmlElement) {
    console.log('a is undefined2:', a == undefined);
    var a;
```

**Returns**:

 a is undefined1: false

  a is undefined2: true

**If the last line *(var a;)* is commented out, this is returned**:

 a is undefined1: false

 a is undefined2: false

I would expect always the latter output.  What do I not know?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting `var a` inside a function creates a different `a` variable that is scoped to that function.

Since you don't assign a value to it, it is undefined.

When you comment it out, you are testing the outer `a` which has the value of 1.

Variables are hoisted. It doesn't matter where in a function you use `var foo`, the `foo` for that function still applies to the whole function.

Comment: aha! hoisting is the magic word.  Found this from another stack overflow.  Thanks!  http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting

Answer (score 1):

Declaring variable within function using `var` makes local copy (new variable) with scope on the whole function - it does not matter whether it is used before it is declared.

Never declare variables without `var`.

If you want to access the golobal variable and you have local variable of the same name, you can access the global `foo` variable using `window.foo`